# Change Gnosis Safe signers programmatically

Tags: gnosis-safe, snapshot

I'm trying to set up a delegated democracy with regular members voting on Snapshot for a limited number of representatives that are allowed to manage the funds in a Gnosis Safe. Is there an integration that allows for that operating model? Basically, I'm looking to use the Snapshot consensus to modify the configuration of signers in a Gnosis Safe. Looking at the available plugins, I see the safesnap integration, but it isn't clear if I can use that to affect the configuration of the safe itself. It seems all transaction types are outbound (interacting with other contracts).
Hope this was clear enough and looking forward to your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can the Zodiac Reality Module (formerly SafeSnap) to execute any transaction. Please reach out to their discord for further questions

Comment: For further questions? What about this question though? I see you posted this as an answer,  but "ask in a different place" is a comment at best.

Comment: To me it is clearly an answer to your question
>  Is there an integration that allows for that operating model?
> you can the Zodiac Reality Module (formerly SafeSnap) to execute any transaction

Comment: I actually specified in the question that I had tried that already and it only allows outbound contract interactions, not changing the actual signers of the safe.

Comment: This is false. In a proposal, you can put a transaction interacting with the Safe to change an owner. You should give it a try again.

Comment: @mikheevm although correct, you made no effort to be helpful. the op could use a pointer in how to build custom transactions

Comment: @NicSzerman feel free to point them

Comment: @mikheevm not interested in doing that

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you managed to do so in the end. Would love to learn how you managed to change owner? Like encoding the data and making a proposal tx?